# Context & Dependency Injection : How to inject implementation of an interface?

Tags: dependency-injection, cdi, javax-inject

I am at beginner stage of CDI and trying to inject the implementation of interface using field injection as below:

AutoService.java

```
package com.interfaces;

public interface AutoService {
    void getService();
}
```

BMWAutoService.java

```
package com.implementations;

import javax.inject.Named;

import com.interfaces.AutoService;

@Named("bmwAutoService")
public class BMWAutoService implements AutoService {

    public BMWAutoService() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void getService() {
        System.out.println("You chose BMW auto service");

    }

}
```

AutoServiceCaller.java

```
package com.interfaces;

public interface AutoServiceCaller {
    void callAutoService();
}
```

AutoServiceCallerImp.java

```
package com.implementations;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import com.interfaces.AutoService;
import com.interfaces.AutoServiceCaller;

public class AutoServiceCallerImp implements AutoServiceCaller {

    @Inject
    @Named("bmwAutoService")
    private AutoService bmwAutoService;

    public AutoServiceCallerImp() {

    }

    @Override
    public void callAutoService() {
        bmwAutoService.getService();

    }

}
```

TestDisplayMessage.java

```
package com.tests;

import com.implementations.AutoServiceCallerImp;
import com.interfaces.AutoServiceCaller;

public class TestDisplayMessage {

    public TestDisplayMessage() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AutoServiceCaller caller = new AutoServiceCallerImp();

        caller.callAutoService();

    }

}
```

When I run `TestDisplayMessage.java` , the expected result would be "You chose BMW auto service" but I get NullPointerException as below :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.implementations.AutoServiceCallerImp.callAutoService(AutoServiceCallerImp.java:21)
    at com.tests.TestDisplayMessage.main(TestDisplayMessage.java:16)
```

Couldn't figure out exactly what I am missing here. Please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems you misunderstood the concept of CDI a bit - the idea is that you leave the bean lifecycle to CDI container. That means CDI will **create** a dispose beans for you. In other words, you are **not** supposed to create beans by calling `new`. If you do that, CDI does not know about it and will not inject anything into it.

If you are in SE environment, which I think you are since you use `main` method to test, you want to use Weld (CDI implementation) SE artifact (I guess you do that).
There, you will need to *start the CDI container*. Note that if you were developing a classical EE application on a server, you don't do this, because the server will handle it for you. Now, the very basic way to boot Weld SE container is:

```
Weld weld = new Weld();
try (WeldContainer container = weld.initialize()) {
  // inside this try-with-resources block you have CDI container booted
  //now, ask it to give you an instance of AutoServiceCallerImpl
  AutoServiceCallerImpl as = container.select(AutoService.class).get();
  as.callAutoService();
}
```

Now, second issue with your code. The usage of `@Named` is intended for EL resolution. E.g. in JFS pages, so you can access the bean directly. **What you probably want** is to differentiate between several `AutoService` implementations and choose a given one. For that CDI has **qualifiers**. Check [this documentation section](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#qualifiers) for more information on how to use them.